# How to stop the browser preload resources before cookie is set

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

There is a cool feature on modern browsers that
When the browser is blocked on a script, a second lightweight parser scans the rest of the markup looking for other resources e.g. stylesheets, scripts, images etc., that also need to be retrieved.

How can I have a `<script>` block as the first element in the `<head>` that simply (in this case simply writes a cookie)

```
<script>
    document.cookie = 'b=p; path=/';
</script>
.....
<img src="/some/image.jpg">
```

And the browser should not preload anything before this script is executed..

The problem is that since the browser does a scan/lookahead and preloads other resources it gets requested without that cookie set..

Is there a way to tell the browser to stop the preload of resources until a given script has finished executing.

Comment: I think you're talking about Chrome's preload feature, and no, it is not possible. If I can find the bug for you, I will post it here, but it is marked: 'WONT FIX'

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86175

Comment: Thanks! (was just looking in the crbug database)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: It would make sense to add a `sync` attribute to opt-out of looking ahead

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, there's no way to stop the browser from preloading resources in markup (and that may very well be extended to resources in scripts and styles in the future).

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the opposite of the script's `async` of attribute. The goal is that those resources ahead of this script should not be preloaded.. only after this script block is evaluated..

Comment: How about setting the cookie on server side instead of JS?

Comment: Due to CDN and load balancer we need to detect via client and only via JS

Comment: If JS is required anyway (though relying on JS this strong is generally undesired), you could load all page content after the cookie is set while initially providing a minimal stub page.

Comment: But SEO and static page is still needed.. We only want the resources to be called with cookie.  Pretty simple I think :)

Comment: Then just resources (probably images) could probably be statically replaced with stubs by default and then dynamically replaced with real images. ;-)

Comment: @MaratTanalin the main point is to serve a regular page served from a pool of servers dedicated to serve real users to users, and serve from a bot pool of servers dedicated to serve bots and crawlers.

The easiest way to do it is to write a cookie and all resources will be requested with this cookie.. no stubs no hacks..